# download a large file TAR using SFTP

Tags: tar, sftp

I am trying to download from a remote server ( in UK I am in the USA)  a large file using SFTP (50GB)

It starts but  (maybe 10% done) it abandons it and says "too large"

Is there another way to get it?

I am unable to untag the file on the remote server (space limitations)

Even transferring the files one at a time into a local folder without actually OPENING the TAR file would be fine too.

I have tried RSYNC too and that does not work either.

Thank you

Comment: offtopic. not a programming question. but did you try gzip -9'ing it?

Comment: What OS are you using? What filesystem are you trying to save the file to? Does it (the file system) have a size limit?

Comment: I _really_ dislike reading "does not work" in a question. In regard to rsync, because it _does work_! If it "doesn't" then the issue lies elsewhere, like the host not allowing log-in shells and arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit on the SFTP protocol as it uses 64bit integers for file offsets. The problem may be on the server software or, more likely, on the client. Try using a different one (i.e., PuTTY, OpenSSH, lftp, FileZilla, WinSCP, etc).

In any case, give us the exact details of the software and version you are using and the commands you have run and the specific error messages and we will be able to provide better help.